# C# .Net ListBox Draw Item, WebControls.ListItem is being added with value, but text is not displayed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

So i have a problem, i have an application that gets some information from a server. Then i make some System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem to store the information and display it in the listbox. On my developer pc, that i use to develop this application, it works fine. The text is being drawn and everything is fine

But when i use another pc, that is not my developer pc, it fails. When i predraw an item with some text it is added properly, but when i use my method it fails, and it does not show the text, but i can still select the item in the listbox, and i can also get the value of the item, but i cannot see the text.

The method for getting the data is:

```
public async void hentMeldingerAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                string name = "";

                name = guid;

                Dictionary<string, Message> items = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => hentMeldinger(name));

                List<uiControls.ListItem> items_list = new List<uiControls.ListItem>();

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Message> pair in items)
                {
                    uiControls.ListItem item = new uiControls.ListItem();

                    item.Text = $"\n  {pair.Value.username} ({Globals.FullControl.UnixTimeStampTilDateTime(double.Parse(pair.Value.timestamp)).ToString("dd:MM HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)})\n\t{pair.Value.message}\n";

                    item.Value = $"{pair.Key}";

                    //Legger til i meldingslisten 
                    try
                    {
                        if (meldinger.ContainsKey(pair.Key))
                        {
                            meldinger.Remove(pair.Key);
                            meldinger.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            meldinger.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (KeyNotFoundException keyerr) {
                        obj = new FeilBehandler("KeyErr HentMeldingerAsync", keyerr.Message, keyerr.ToString(), true);
                    }



                }

                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    if (items_list.Count > -1)
                    {
                        lbsMessage.BeginUpdate();
                        lbsMessage.Items.Clear();
                        lbsMessage.Items.AddRange(items_list.ToArray());
                        lbsMessage.EndUpdate();
                        lbsMessage.TopIndex = lbsMessage.Items.Count - 1;

                    }
                }));
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException opex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(opex.ToString());
                obj = new FeilBehandler("HentMeldingerAsync()", opex.Message, opex.ToString(), true);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception err) {
            MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
            obj = new FeilBehandler("HentMeldingerAsync()", err.Message, err.ToString(), true);
        }

    }
```

This calls another method, that gets the data and poulates a Dictionary with information, the information is always recived in this case, and its not lack of information that is the problem.

I also apply custom design onto the ListBox, bu using the DrawItem Event, here is it as follows:

```
private void Messages_box_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Dette skjer når man skriver gjenstanden til listen grafisk

            if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
                e = new DrawItemEventArgs(e.Graphics,
                                          e.Font,
                                          e.Bounds,
                                          e.Index,
                                          e.State ^ DrawItemState.Selected,
                                          e.ForeColor,
                                          (Color)ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#8b9dc3"));



            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
            string text = lbsMessage.Items[e.Index].ToString();
            bool containsProsjektleder = text.Contains("Prosjektleder");
            bool containsBilder = text.Contains(" - (Bilder)");

            e.DrawBackground();
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lbsMessage.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush((Color)ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#3b5998")), e.Bounds);
            e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            obj = new FeilBehandler("Message_Draw_Item", err.Message, err.ToString(), true);
        }
    }
```

And i also use the MeasureItem Event:

```
private void Messages_box_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
    {
        //Dette skjer når man måler gjenstanden
        try
        {
            //Oppretter en objektreferanse til Listeboksen i variabelen 'sender'


            //Setter høyden til meldinggjenstanden i listeboksen etter hvor mange linjehopp det er. 
            e.ItemHeight = (int)((TellNyLinje((lbsMessage.Items[e.Index].ToString()), "\n") + 1) * (lbsMessage.Font.GetHeight() + 2));
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Messages_box_MeasureItem(sender, e);
            //Her blir ikke feil behandlet
        }
    }
```

Now im not going to be prideful, and say that the drawitem or the measure item has the problem, but i have tried to normally add items to the listbox and it draws properly, even on the machine that the problem occours.

So to sum it up. The machine gets the info from the database, it adds it into items, and if i try to get the Value it gets the value, but the text does not display in the lisbox, i can still select the item, however its just selection, not text. But when i add a listbox item beforehand it draws perfectly.

I really would appriciate help with this issue, and sorry for my horrible english, my mother tounge is not english.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you ever invalidate the listbox after adding the item?

Comment: No i dont invalidate it, should i ?

Comment: Yes, I think you should. Doing it from an async function you will need to Invoke it..

Comment: yea i am invoking the updating and adding of items in the listbox. But since this works on my pc, but not on the clients pc, can this be due to the System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem that is being used. I dont suppose so but it could have something to do with the fact.